# Rails 4 - How to configure google calendar using `fullcalendar_engine` gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

In Rails 4.1.4, I am using `fullcalendar_engine` gem to implement a calendar app. I have  tried to connect it with a google calendar by referring http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/. After adding this feature(as mentioned below)  events are not showing in calendar. If I removed `googleCalendarApiKey & events` options then events will display in calendar.

In views,

```
<p>
<%= link_to 'Create Event', 'javascript:void()', :id=> 'new_event' %>
<%= link_to 'Home', "/" %>
</p>
<div>
  <div class='calendar'></div>
</div>
<div id="event_desc_dialog" class="dialog" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="create_event_dialog" class="dialog" style ="display:none;">
   <%= render 'form' %>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
   var options = { theme: true, defaultView: 'month',
   dayRender: function(date, element, view){
     var tomorrow = new Date();
     var yesterday = new Date();
     var newdate = new Date();
     var nDate = newdate.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
     var tDate = newdate.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
     if(date < nDate ) {
       $(element).css("background", "url(/assets/images.jpg)");
     }
     else if(date >= tDate) {
       $(element).css("background", "url(/assets/grey_bg.jpg)");
     }
    },
   googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCNvxER_fEdg2kETqtaPw6Pw8g0CIH9lOg12345shjkrajat',
   events: {
     googleCalendarId: 'cccapp@gmail.com',
     error: function() {
       alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
     }
   }
 };

  $('.calendar').fullCalendar($.extend(full_calendar_options,options));
  $('#new_event').click(function(event) {
    FullcalendarEngine.Form.display()
    event.preventDefault();
  });
 });
</script>
```

How can I connect this fullcalendar to google calendar?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: It is not showing any error. After adding an events, it will not show in calendar & mail will not go to gmail(cccapp@gmail.com).

Comment: I should have been more clear. Do you see any JavaScript error in developer console on browser?

Comment: Yea. I have checked it, there is no error.